# Application domain restarts on node publish - Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, iis, umbraco

Whenever I publish a node on Umbraco 6.2.5, the application domain restarts.

The log shows:  Application shutdown. Reason: ConfigurationChange

The only files that are modified during the publish are in *App_Data*: Umbraco.config and the contents of TEMP\ExamineIndexes.

I have no real time virus scanning hitting those files.  Any ideas on how to prevent this?  FCNMode = disabled did not resolve the issue.

```
    2015-03-08 16:05:50,611 [15] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Publishing.PublishingStrategy - [Thread 7] Content 'test3' with Id '2292' has been published.
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,517 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Determining hash of code files on disk
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,533 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Hash determined (took 7ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,549 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Starting resolution types of umbraco.interfaces.IApplicationStartupHandler
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,580 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Completed resolution of types of umbraco.interfaces.IApplicationStartupHandler, found 25 (took 26ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,611 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyEditorValueConverter
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,611 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyEditorValueConverter, found 0 (took 2ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,611 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyValueConverter
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,611 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.IPropertyValueConverter, found 12 (took 0ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController, found 5 (took 0ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiController
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiController, found 3 (took 0ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IThumbnailProvider
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IThumbnailProvider, found 3 (took 0ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IImageUrlProvider
    2015-03-08 16:05:51,642 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 11] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.Media.IImageUrlProvider, found 1 (took 0ms)
    2015-03-08 16:05:52,174 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Search.ExamineEvents - [Thread 11] Initializing Examine and binding to business logic events
    2015-03-08 16:05:52,174 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Search.ExamineEvents - [Thread 11] Adding examine event handlers for index providers: 3
    2015-03-08 16:05:52,314 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 22] Setting OriginalRequestUrl: dev.foo.com:80/umbraco
    2015-03-08 16:05:52,486 [15] INFO  Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - [Thread 22] Application shutdown. Reason: ConfigurationChange
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're currently investigating this issue which might be related to the Microsoft KB3000850 patch. Can you confirm that this patch was installed before you started getting these issues?

Comment: I can confirm KB3000850 was installed on Win 2012 x64 server last November.  I don't have server logs handy from that period, but the application restarts on publish did seem to start appearing around that time.

Comment: Alright, that helps. I'll report back here on our findings.

Comment: @sebastiaan Any news on this? We are experiencing the same issues over here. :(

Comment: @gijswijs Talking to Microsoft.. it will take a while. Only thing we can advise for now is to uninstall the update.

Comment: @Sebastiaan that's what we did with positive results so far.

Comment: Uninstalling Microsoft KB3000850 patch also resolved the issue for me.  Thanks for your work on this @sebastiaan

Comment: Update: MS confirms that it's due this patch which is included in KB3000850 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3007507 - so just removing KB3007507 should be enough. The issue is in our tracker here if you want to subscribe to email updates: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6338

Comment: in case anybody has not had a notification from the issue tracker, MS has provided us with a pre-release patch, please read the notes from Shannon here: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6338#comment=67-20138

Comment: MS have released a public patch for this now: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052480

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would delete umbraco.config and restart apppol.

Also could this be a permissions issue?  Test this by making sure sure you apppol user has full permissions on all files folders in website.

Comment: Thanks for your input but unfortunately that doesn't resolve the issue.  I've verified the application pool identity the website runs under has full control permissions on the website.  WIndows indexing of any of the web files is disabled, as is real-time anti-virus monitoring.  .